# How can i create different testing profiles in Maven

Tags: maven

Our J2EE web application is ready for production.
Now we want to manage different environments like dev , sit , uat , prod for testing.
Therefore , we need to create different profiles in maven .
What plugins should be used ?

Comment: Simply wrong way cause your application should be independent  of your environment. And profiles is the wrong cause you can't activate all the needed profiles in one go...so you can't produces correct releases with this way...If you really will go the wrong path and produce artifacts per environment I can give you idea github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Maven profile fit your need?

If you need to personalize the commands depending your environment. You can set-up the profile and the build step associated to each profile.

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>appserverConfig-dev</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>env</name>
          <value>dev</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <appserver.home>/path/to/dev/appserver</appserver.home>
      </properties>
    </profile>
```

From the introduction guide:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html